# Marathi column data translation to english

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have some [Marathi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathi_language) OwnerNames stored in my table, I want to translate it to English inside API.

I am using c# mvc API

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathi_language

Comment: ASP.NET strings are Unicode strings. `nvarchar` fields in SQL Server are Unicode fields as well. You don't have to convert anything to English. You **definitely** don't need to convert anything to UTF8 - that what ASP.NET itself does by default when it generates HTML.

Comment: @SurentharP that linked question has nothing to do with *this* question. Besides, ASP.NET uses Unicode natively. So does SQL Server. No tricks or conversions are needed. StackOverflow is an ASP.NET site which is why I can write Αυτό Εδώ knowing it will be displayed without any problems

Comment: @SurajS. as you see, I can paste `Varhadi (Varhādi) (वऱ्हाडी) or Vaidarbhi (वैदर्भी)` from [the Wikipeda article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathi_language#Varhadi) and have it displayed in SO just fine. Are you asking how to *transliterate* the text using English characters ?

Comment: Well, do you really need to translate the strings stored in that column in marathi lang to english lang or you have an issue to store marathi symbols to that column?

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, yes  i want to translate the text using English characters

Comment: @ Sam , i dont have any  issue to store marathi symbols to the column ,i just want to translate it in English lang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an actual translation (like to approximate the *meaning* in English), you'll either need a professional translator (recommended), or you could get an approximate translation by calling out to a [Google Translate](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) or [Microsoft Translator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/translator-api/) API.

However, based on your use case of people's names, it sounds like what you want is to transliterate Marathi characters into an approximation of the sound in English letters, rather than a translation into English. If that's the case, you could probably write a function based loosely on [the method Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Module:mr-translit) uses.

The code that Wikipedia's mr-translit module implements is a series of rules for string replacement using successive Regex.Replace operations. Note that the code is in PHP, but it shouldn't be too hard to mimic their approach by translating the rules into C#. There are too many rules in their example for me to try to translate the whole of the code here, but the approach they've taken is to normalize a few combining diacritic patterns, then attempt to identify distinct words, and successively replace patterns until all that's left is romanized characters. Finally, the string is returned in Unicode Normalization Form C (presumably in case there are other non-Marathi characters in there). In .Net this is the method String.Normalize; in the PHP code from Wikipedia it looks like mw.ustring.toNFC(text)

Comment: looks complicated but i will try this. thanks @JasonTrue